# How to add a table to Docusign template via API?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a template in docusign and can use it to create an envelope using all fields available.

The problem is one of the fields should be a table with a variable length of rows, so I cannot use auto placing because I don't know how many will exists upfront.

The only solution I found till now is to create a brand new word document and upload it to create the envelope, but this is causing problems since this document is taking at lest 10 seconds to be parsed by docusign, probably due to its size.

The best solution will be to have a template and it could be possible to send a "table" field.

Anyone got this before? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps put the table on a second document that you create dynamically? Remember that an envelope can have multiple documents. The signing experience proceeds from one document to the next.

Comment: This is the best solution yet, but still not the perfect one.
This table should be in the middle of the document, this way it goes to the end and I need to insert a reference in document saying that this table is in the end.

Comment: Just received a response from docusign support and this feature is not supported, so this is the best solution we can get.

These are the words from Docusign: "Unfortunately, there is no possible way to add a variable length in text fields, or in any other fields for the document. Anyways, you can always re-size the text field to fit for the length of any text."

Comment: Thanks for the check. Perhaps you could split the original document into three parts/three new docs: the front, the table, the back. Because the DocuSign signing ceremony shows one doc after the next, it might work out as you wish.

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing this, but right now seems that just two documents will be sufficient. Another detail is to download files later, I'm downloading them combined so for the user seems like one document.